# MS Access Force Update on Combobox

Tags: vba, ms-access

How do I force an update when the ComboBox value is changed in code. Below is piece of code I have tried but does not seem to work

```
 If (Not Mid(sCode, 1, 2) = ddlLevelID1) Then
     ddlLevelID1 = Mid(sCode, 1, 2) 'force change/force AFTER_UPDATE event to run. 
 End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `ddlLevelID1` is the ComboBox:

```
ddlLevelID1.value = foo
```

will change the value. I do not believe you can link a value displayed in a ComboBox to a variable value without pushing changes up to the userform after the value is changed.

---

Regarding the AfterUpdate method, from msdn:

> Changing data in a control by using Visual Basic or a macro containing
>   the SetValue action doesn't trigger these events for the control.
>   However, if you then move to another record or save the record, the
>   form's AfterUpdate event does occur.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238392(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Are you saying that changing the value does not FORCE the after update event to be triggered? Cause that is still what is happening.

Comment: What do you mean "force the after update event" ? You can call the method by simply doing `call ComboBox1_AfterUpdate` as well